# JAVAFX LineChart Thread

Tags: multithreading, javafx, linechart

Help me to realize the Line Chart and how to do better.
I need to add a Line Chart 2-3 The schedule of 30 - the values reach from the database. I wanted to make a separate stream, but there are errors.

> ERROR : 'Exception in thread "Thread-4"
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread;
>   currentThread = Thread-4''

```
import extfx.scene.chart.DateAxis;
import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class main extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static LineChart<Date, Number> lineChart;
    public static Thread threadInTrendFlow;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("-----------------------");

        NumberAxis numberAxis = new NumberAxis();
        DateAxis dateAxis = new DateAxis();
        lineChart = new LineChart<Date, Number>(dateAxis,numberAxis);

        lineChart.getData().add(scFlow.series);

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(lineChart);
        ///
        Button inLineChart = new Button("insert");
        inLineChart.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Task<Void> loaded = new scFlow();
                threadInTrendFlow = new Thread(loaded);
                threadInTrendFlow.start();
            }
        });
        pane.setTop(inLineChart);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane,800,600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Platform.runlater(()->{}) when invoking stuff that goes on the application thread.

There are plenty of threads related to somewhat similar problems. Just search multithreading javafx.